# Sweetalert en PHP

Tags: php, sweetalert

Intento que cuando el usuario ingrese sus datos de LOGIN, si alguno es incorrecto, se muestre un alerta utilizando Sweetalert en PHP. Vengo leyendo e intentando, pero no encuentro mi error. Soy novato, auto-aprendiendo.
La idea es que al hacer clic en INGRESAR (está en login_sistema.php), aparezca el cuadro de error (sweetalert) y el usuario modifique los datos (en la misma página ya abierta). Pero al tocar en INGRESAR, se carga la página de logueo (que el usuario no debe ver), aparece el sweetalert y al aceptarlo se carga la página de login[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias!
Este es mi código, el cual funciona correctamente para ingresar:

```
    <header>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sweetalert2.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sweetalert2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>  
</header>
<?php
    session_start();
    include("conexion.php");
    $dni=$_POST['0dni'];
    $mail=$_POST['0mail'];
    $psw=$_POST['0psw'];
    if (empty($dni)||empty($mail)||empty($psw)) {
        header("location:login_sistema.php?error=FALTAN%20DATOS"); // NO DEBERÍA APARECER, PORQUE EL FORMULARIO DE LOGIN OBLIGA A COMPLETAR TODOS LOS CAMPOS
    } else {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE dni='$dni' and mail='$mail'";
        $consulta=mysqli_query($acceso,$sql);
        $existe=mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_row($consulta);
        if (($existe==1) and (password_verify($psw, $row[6]))) {
            $_SESSION['dni'] = "$dni";
            setcookie("user_dni", $row[2]);
            setcookie("user_apellido", $row[3]);
            setcookie("user_nombre", $row[4]);
            setcookie("user_mail", $row[5]);
            header("location:secretaria.php");
        } else {
       header("location:login_sistema.php?login=false");
        }
    }
}
?>  

Código login_sistema.php

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
        <head> 
            <!-- Required meta tags -->
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imta.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imta_login.css">
            <!-- Otros -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sweetalert2.css"/>
                <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/sweetalert2.js"></script>            
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="logueo.php" method="post">
                <div class="container-fluid align-items-center">
                    <div id="input-container">
                        <b class="login-iconos">* D.N.I. N°:</b>
                        <input id="txt_dni" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm txt" name="0dni" placeholder="Incluir los puntos (12.345.678)" required title="Escriba su número de documento, incluyendo los puntos." size="10" maxlength="10" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div id="input-container">
                        <b class="login-iconos">* E-mail:</b>
                        <input id="txt_mail" type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm txt" name="0mail" required title="Escriba su dirección de e-mail." placeholder="usuario@dominio.com">
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    <div id="input-container">
                        <b class="login-iconos">* Contraseña:</b>
                        <input id="txt_psw" type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm txt" name="0psw" required title="Escriba su contraseña (el sistema distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas).">
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="divbtn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn" id="btn_ingresar"><b> INGRESAR</b></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['login'])=='false') {                    
            echo '<script>
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: "error",
                    title: "¡ERROR!",
                    text: "Alguno de los datos ingresados, es incorrecto. Intenta de nuevo.",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "ACEPTAR"
                });
            </script>';
        }
    ?>  
            </form>           
            <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
            <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ¿Y que error te da? ¿Y donde está el código para llamar al sweetalert?  Pon el codigo de login_sistema.php para ver como lo has intentado, pues alli es donde debemos mirar si quieres ayuda.

Comment: Hola @masterguru ahí modifico el código... Gracias por decirme lo del código, copié uno viejo... Gracias!

Comment: La idea es que al hacer clic en INGRESAR (está en login_sistema.php), aparezca el cuadro de error (sweetalert) y el usuario modifique los datos (en la misma página ya abierta). Pero al tocar en INGRESAR, se carga la página de logueo (que el usuario no debe ver), aparece el sweetalert y al aceptarlo se carga la página de login.

Comment: Supongo que lo que quieres es simplemente comentar o quitar esto:  `if(result.value){ window.location = "login_sistema.php";}`

Comment: @masterguru Se lo he quitado, pero me aparece en la página de logueo. Para contextualizar... el usuario ingreso a login_sistema.php y, al tocar INGRESAR, se "ejecuta" logueo.php, para dirigir a secretaria.php, pero... si hay errores en los datos ingresados, el sweetalert me lo muestra en logueo.php, página que el usuario nunca debería ver.

Comment: Ponnos la pagina de **login_sistema.php** tambien, sino vamos a ciegas, pues creo que lo puedes condensar todo en una de hecho y asi no pierdes los datos introducidos al saltar de una a otra.

Comment: @masterguru Ahí publiqué el código... no había pensado poner todo en el mismo archivo... no se me ocurrió...

Comment: No lo pongas como respuesta, haras enfadar a los moderadores.  Debes ponerlo en la propia pregunta editandola de nuevo.

Comment: @masterguru Gracias por tu ayuda constante... no se enojen :-)

Comment: Es un poco marrano, pero podrias probar sustituyendo `window.location = "login_sistema.php";` por `history.back()`.. a ver que te sale

Comment: @masterguru Me ha pasado lo mismo... agregué captura de pantalla con el error.

Comment: Si, claro, eso te va a pasar siempre, porque lo envias alli con tu formulario.  Si eso es lo que te molesta entonces debes usar ajax en lugar de enviarlo por action mediante POST.  ¿Si ahora le das a Aceptar no te vuelve a la página anterior con los datos para editar?  Eso es lo que pretendia con el history.back()

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista tienes dos opciones: 1)  Lo pones todo en la misma página, condicionando lo que quieres mostrar segun venga del formulario o no. 2) Usas ajax para llamar a logueo.php. En ambos casos hay que reescribir código y cambiar cosas, y eso debes hacerlo tu porque son cambios mayores.

Comment: Mi solución del history.back(), aunque no era ideal, la veia suficiente para regresar a la página anterior recuperando los datos introducidos a pesar que la URL cambiaba mientras se mostraba el alert y se veria lo del logueo.php, a lo que no le doy demasiada importancia porque si alguien te quiere atacar por fuerza bruta tambien lo ve en el action del formulario y lo hara igualmente aunque pretendas esconderlo.

Comment: GRACIAS @masterguru, voy a intentar hacerlo todo es la misma página, no se me había ocurrido esa opción. En cuanto lo haga y logre, les cuento...

Comment: @masterguru He podido solucionar mi problema: en logueo.php, cuando alguno de los datos no es correcto, puse un valor mediante el método GET, el cual tomo en login_sistema.php, y si el mismo es falso, me muestra el sweetalert que tanto deseaba. En los códigos que publiqué anteriormente, ya figuran las actualizaciones. Gracias! Espero no sea desprolijo... pero para los primeros pasos, creo vengo bien.

Comment: Me alegro pues :-)... aunque en lugar de modificar la pregunta habrias tenido que poner la respuesta tu mismo para que vean que ya esta resuelto y como lo has hecho. Al cabo de unas 12 horas tu mismo te la puedes aceptar y asi no quedara pendiente eternamente de responder.

Comment: @masterguru GRACIAS por ayudarme y tendré en cuenta esas reglas del foro y que nadie se enoje jaja